# Electromagnetic Induction - An Experiment

Tags: electricity

I am currently working on a personal project where I am investigating Electromagnetic Induction.

My set up includes two loops - one primary and one secondary. The primary loop is hooked up to a Transistor which converts the DC output of a 9V battery in AC. This is also hooked up to a 33k Ohm resistor.

The secondary coil is hooked up first to a bulb to test whether the circuit is functioning and then it connected to a Multimeter to measure induced voltage in the secondary coil.

My setup works as the bulb has lit up on each attempt. However the problem arises as I increase the number of coils on the secondary loop. The induced maximum voltage induced rises as I increase the number of coils on the secondary. However, if I increase the number of coils above a certain number, the induced maximum voltage stays the same and doesn't increase.

My question is why does this happen?

Comment: Could this be due to "magnetic saturation"? See this link: https://www.duramag.com/techtalk/tech-briefs/magnetic-saturation-understanding-limitations-to-induced-magnetism-achieved-in-workpiece/

Comment: (a) Are you measuring the voltage across the secondary on open circuit, that is without the bulb connected across it? (b) Are you using a multimeter on its ac voltage range? (c) Are you sure that the frequency of ac that you are using is within the range of frequencies that the multimeter will handle?

Comment: (a) I am removing the bulb and connecting the multi meter in series. (b) Yes I am using it on the AC Voltage range. It is on mV. (c) I am pretty sure my multimeter is in the frequency as it worked for the lower number of wires.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my assembly of the coils, I was making them in such a way that they overlapped. Hence something called the masking effect happened where not all the coils were being exposed to the magnetic field created. Hence it was the same as if they were not present. Now I re did the experiment taking care to not to cross the wire over each other and now I get a constant increase.